# How to prevent github from highlighting apostrophes at my react code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github

So github is highlighting this part of my code as an error because the apostrophe wont close anywhere.

[image: problem]

but the problem is, this is HTML code inside a JS react file, inside the render function.

an example that would trigger this problem on a github pull request is :

```
render = () => (
  <a>Signer's Title</a>
)
```

everything after the apostrophe would be highlighted in red.

bad solutions :
`` {`'`} ``
or using a JSX file which is dont want to.

Comment: you could use an html entity: &apos;

Comment: yeah but that way my code is not that clean just to trick github

Comment: I wouldn't say using html entities is dirty, I know what you are saying but html entities are safe. But the answer below is good as well.

Comment: Why don't you want to use a JSX file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a single quote `'` as an apostrophe.

I think you could use the apostrophe character `‎’` to avoid this.

example :

```
render = () => (
  <a>Signer’s Title</a>
)
```